# How to extract a part of string in RDD?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

After a few transformations, this is the output of the RDD I have:

```
( z287570731_serv80i:7:175 , 5:Re )
( p286274731_serv80i:6:100 , 138 )
( t219420679_serv37i:2:50 , 5 )
( v290380588_serv81i:12:800 , 144:Jo )
( z292902510_serv83i:4:45 , 5:Re )
```

Using this data as an input RDD, I'd like to extract the value between the two semicolons.

Eg :

```
Input = ( z287570731_serv80i:7:175 , 5:Re )
Output = 7 (:7:)
```

This is how I'm trying to do it

```
    val processedRDD = tid.map{ 
    case (inString, inInt) => 
      val RegEx = """.*:([\d.]+):.*""".r
      val table_level = RegEx.findFirstIn(inString)
    }

    processedRDD.collect().foreach(println)
```

This is the output I'm getting:

```
()
()
()
()
()
()
()
```

How to do it Spark-way?

Comment: This quote from Jamie Zawinski must be said: 
Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Comment: I'm a newbie to programming in general and Scala and Spark. Please suggest a better/more efficient solution.

Comment: I would go with @shankar Koirala 's solution.

Comment: What Spark version do you use?

Comment: 2.1.1 @ Jacek Laskowski

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very nice answers here, but I've missed one that I *believe* can easily beat them all :) And that's exactly why I love Scala - for its flexibility.

### Solution

```
scala> val solution = rdd.
  map { case (left, right) => left }.
  map(_.split(":")).
  map { case Array(_, takeMe, _) => takeMe }.
  collect
solution: Array[String] = Array(7, 6, 2, 12, 4)
```

I *believe* that the solution is hardly to beat for readability and comprehension. It just says what it does (like a good poem).

### Explanation

The following is your RDD (in a nicely formatted output thanks to Spark SQL's `Dataset.show`).

```
scala> rdd.toDF.show(false)
+-------------------------+------+
|_1                       |_2    |
+-------------------------+------+
|z287570731_serv80i:7:175 |5:Re  |
|p286274731_serv80i:6:100 |138   |
|t219420679_serv37i:2:50  |5     |
|v290380588_serv81i:12:800|144:Jo|
|z292902510_serv83i:4:45  |5:Re  |
+-------------------------+------+

// Compare to this assembler-like way and you understand why you should use Spark SQL for this
scala> rdd.foreach(println)
(z287570731_serv80i:7:175,5:Re)
(p286274731_serv80i:6:100,138)
(t219420679_serv37i:2:50,5)
(v290380588_serv81i:12:800,144:Jo)
(z292902510_serv83i:4:45,5:Re)
```

The first step is to remove the right column. Pattern matching FTW!

```
scala> rdd.map { case (left, right) => left }.foreach(println)
z292902510_serv83i:4:45
t219420679_serv37i:2:50
v290380588_serv81i:12:800
p286274731_serv80i:6:100
z287570731_serv80i:7:175
```

With the temporary RDD, you split the strings using `:` as a separator and take the second word. Again Scala's pattern matching FTW!

```
val oneColumnOnly = rdd.map { case (left, right) => left }
scala> oneColumnOnly.
  map(_.split(":")).  // <-- split
  map { case Array(_, takeMe, _) => takeMe }. // <-- take the 2nd field
  foreach(println)
6
12
4
2
7
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it with DataFrames and SparkSQL

```
val rddToDf = rdd.toDF
rddToDf.createOrReplacetempView("df")
spark.sql("select substr(_1, instr(_1,':')+1, instr(substr(_1, instr(_1,':')+1), ':')-1) as f  from df").show //spark can be SparkSession or SQLContext
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is a fixed pattern than you can split the first value from rdd as

```
rdd.map( row => row._1.split(":")(1))
```

Which gives `[7 6 2 12 4]`

To get `[:7: :6: :2: :12: :4:]`

```
rdd.map( ":" + row => row._1.split(":")(1) + ":")
```

Hope this helps

Comment: can I extract two patterns separately from a single RDD?

Comment: Like I have a String "Hello, World". I give """.*e([\d.]+)0.*""".r and """.*w([\d.]+)l.*""".r together in a single statement.

Answer (score 0):

The value of a compound expression, scoped with `{}` is the last value in the scope itself.

Your last line in the pattern match for the `map` call is `val table_level = ...` which is an assignment and returns `()` of type `Unit`.

you should simply not assign it to anything but write the expression like

```
val processedRDD = tid.map{ 
  case (inString, inInt) => 
    val RegEx = """.*:([\d.]+):.*""".r
    RegEx.findFirstIn(inString)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the first element of tuple on `:` if it's always going to be like that and do another `map` to get the desired output.

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Array(( "z287570731_serv80i:7:175" , "5:Re" ),
      ( "p286274731_serv80i:6:100" , "138" ),
      ( "t219420679_serv37i:2:50" , "5" ),
      ( "v290380588_serv81i:12:800" , "144:Jo" ),
      ( "z292902510_serv83i:4:45" , "5:Re" ) ))
val mapped = rdd.map( x => x._1.split(":")(1) ).map( x => ":"+x+":")
mapped.collect()
res1: Array[String] = Array(:7:, :6:, :2:, :12:, :4:)
```

Comment: You won't need two maps, isn't that so?

Comment: Yeah, not necessary. Can be accomplished with one.